Pagination with unique column and total count
I trying to query mongo collection with unique column and pagination using mongoose.
I have pagination data that I need to know the total unique counts, offset/page number but the query is needs to be executed without $skip and $limit, which returns entire collection and eating up memory just to get the count. I tried using distinct
await Token.find().distinct('token_id').countDocuments().exec()

which is not giving the correct unique count.
Its been a while working on mongo, from what I learnt that aggregates collects all the records, then filters/group and sends the results back. Which is fine for me, as long as the node app is not doing any memory intensive operations.
So, how do I achieve the total unique records (without fetching the collection if possible just the count) and pagination to work in right way.
Below is the mongoose model Token and grouping by token_id to fetch unique records. (its expected that there might be duplicates token_id)
const getUniqueTokens = async () => {
  return Token.aggregate([{
      $group: {
        _id: `$token_id`,
        // Get the first document for each unique field
        doc: {
          $first: "$$ROOT"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      $replaceRoot: {
        // Replace root to get back the original document structure
        newRoot: "$doc"
      }
    },
    {
      $skip: offset,
    },
    {
      $limit: 100
    }
  ]).exec();
};


Your aggregation pipeline is mostly fine - you should add a $sort stage so that you're reliably paginating 1, 2, 3, 4 always. Instead of 3, 2, 1, 4 sometimes and 2, 4, 1, 3 other times. (Btw, your aggregation pipeline has backticks around `$token_id` - it should be single or double quotes as I've done below.)
Get the total unique records by putting a $count stage after the group and removing everything else. Execute that as a separate aggregation query.
Aggregation pipeline and Mongo Playground for pagination:
db.token.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$token_id",
      // Get the first document for each unique field
      doc: { $first: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      // Replace root to get back the original document structure
      newRoot: "$doc"
    }
  },
  { $sort: { token_id: 1 } },  // ADDED THIS STAGE
  { $skip: offset },
  { $limit: 100 }
])

Aggregation pipeline and Mongo Playground for the total:
db.token.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$token_id",
      // Get the first document for each unique field
      doc: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  { $count: "total" }
])

You could do both in one aggregation using a $unionWith but I don't recommend that, since getting the result and then extracting the "total" item separately from the actual documents is an unnecessary complication.

great. missed that sort. thank you.

how does this will work, when databased is clustered? will be there any query performance?

also, when i pass invalid column, the  total is 1. https://mongoplayground.net/p/p04ssPoUnvp

When the column for $group --> _id is invalid or non-existent, it evaluates to null. Which is like saying "group all documents". You can see this by adding a $push to know which docs match: https://mongoplayground.net/p/y2IKHHPjS5J. Anyway, why/how would a query work correctly if provided with invalid or non-existent fields? You need to handle such situations in the pipeline or not provide invalid fields.

When running on sharded collections, "If the pipeline includes a sorting or grouping stage, and the allowDiskUse setting is enabled, the merge runs on a randomly-selected shard." Since you are not enabling that, it would probably run on all shards and have results combined. "To see how the pipeline was split, include the explain option in the db.collection.aggregate() method." From: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-sharded-collections/

its just a typo, it got my eye.

Yup, when the group id is null (aka all documents), then the result would be just one accumulated document. So $count would be 1.
